# ERROR: recursive inside the trigger function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.2

This my trigger that will trigger if new value is inserted in origin.

I want to store the result of recursive to table(extract).

I get this error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "perform"
> LINE 10: perform * from "test";
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 221

```
BEGIN

WITH RECURSIVE "test" as

    (select "node_f", "node_2", "edge"
    from "con" where "node_f"= new."origin"
    union
    select O."node_f", O."node_2", O."edge"
    FROM "test" N
    JOIN "con" O on O."node_f" = N."node_2")
    
Select * from "test";

INSERT INTO "extract"
SELECT * FROM "test";

return new;
END;
```

Comment: Why are you using 4 obsolete versions?

Comment: The syntax error mentions `perform`. Where is that keyword in your code?

Comment: You have duplicated `Select * from "test";` for some reason. Remove the first occurrence, the `INSERT` statement should be part of the `WITH`, not a separate statement (with a semicolon in between).